# Errors while integrating GameCenter

Tags: ios, xcode5, game-center

So, I've been trying to add GameCenter to my app for the last couple days, i found a few tutorials none seems to be working too well, so this is the code i have come up with to log in when a player opens the app

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler =
    [localPlayer authenticate];
}


GKLocalPlayer.authenticationHandler = ^(UIViewController *loginVC,
                                      NSError *error)
{
    if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated) {

        [self enableGameCenterForPlayer:[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer]];
    }
    else if (loginVC) {

        [self pauseGame];
        [self presentLoginVC:loginVC];
    }
    else {

        [self disableGameCenter];
    }
};
```

but I'm getting 2 errors and i have no idea what they mean, I'm very new so somethings make sense and some dont, this is one of those, i think ive seen about 9 or 10 different ways of doing this.

Thought it just best to ask those that know

Here's a screenshot of the errors

[image: Errors]

Thank you guys n girls, i appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is simply no authenticate method in the documentation. "To authenticate the local player, retrieve the shared instance of the local player by calling the localPlayer class method and set its authenticateHandler", so the first erroneous line should be deleted. The second erroneous line should refer to localPlayer and be moved into the method:

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

    LocalPlayer.authenticationHandler = ^(UIViewController *loginVC,
                                          NSError *error)
    {
         ...
```

Comment: sorry little confused as to what you mean?

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more clear. It looks like you may need to study up on using blocks as well. A variable with a block is not added like a method, but called within a method.